# Creating a new overlay

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i type this command in the terminal `rosws init ~/fuerte_workspace /opt/ros/fuerte`
the result is

```
smart-engineers@smartengineers-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ rosws init ~/fuerte_workspace /opt/ros/fuerte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosws", line 52, in <module>
    import rosinstall.rosws_cli
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    import wstool.helpers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wstool/helpers.py", line 37, in <module>
    from wstool.config_elements import SetupConfigElement
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wstool/config_elements.py", line 38, in <module>
    from vcstools.vcs_abstraction import get_vcs_client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vcstools/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from vcstools.svn import SvnClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vcstools/svn.py", line 44, in <module>
    import dateutil.parser  # For parsing date strings
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 24, in <module>
    from six import text_type, binary_type, integer_types
ImportError: No module named six
```

plz need an urgent help to get rid of this error???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155841/creating-a-new-overlay/) by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your python packages are either out-of-date or missing dependencies.

Since it's referencing python modules in /usr/local/, I assume you've installed rosws through pip. If that isn't what you were expecting, you should probably try to uninstall the pip version.

My best guess is that you're missing the `six` library, and possibly other dependencies. I would try to run: `sudo pip install -U rosws` to get the latest version of rosws, and hopefully that will pull in the required dependencies as well. If it doesn't, you could try running `sudo pip install six` and see if that helps.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on 2014-04-21**:
i am very thankful to your help ,,,
when i type the """sudo pip install -U rosws""" in the terminal the output is """ smart-engineers@smartengineers-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo pip install -U rosws
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in 
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
"""
How can i get rid of this???

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-22**:
It sounds like your python installation is seriously broken. I suggest searching the internet for that error message or posting on one of the message boards for your linux distribution.